# Mule Deployment on Mule version 3.7.1

Tags: api, deployment, mule

I am getting the below error during deployment. Would like to know the actual reason for this error. Is this related to any licensing issue as the api is working locally as expected.

(org.mule.module.management.agent.WrapperManagerAgent - Mule is embedded in a container already launched by a wrapper.Duplicates will not be registered. Use the org.tanukisoftware.wrapper:type=WrapperManager MBean instead for control)

Thx in advance

Comment: What deployment model are you using, and whats actions are you taking to package and deploy your application?

Comment: I am using mule standalone server for deployment. In order to package the project, i export the project using (Any Point Studio Project to Mule deployable achieve). Once exported, a copy of the same in provided in the apps folder of  mule sever.